# Changing port on Apache doesn't work (using IZ-WAMP)

Tags: php, apache, wamp

I'm using IZ-WAMP https://sourceforge.net/projects/iz-wamp/ for PHP/Wordpress locally.

In their tray menu, on can access to httpd.conf

I changed port to 80 with

Define IZ_WAMP_HTTP_PORT   "80"

But after restarting Apache, localhost doesn't work anymore.

Update after answer: I can't see any port 80 used by any app, and for httpd.exe I can only see "http" which is weird.

Comment: Open cmd and run "netstat -aon | findstr :80" to see if it free or not

Comment: @JohnDoe I see [::]:80 [::]:0 LISTENING 15484 but have no idea what it means :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the problem is solved, fine!

How to change IZ-WAMP Wordpress port 8080 to 80:

1-go to http://localhost:8080/wordpress to check it works fine

2-go to http://localhost:8080/adminer (or by de IZ-WAMP Menu "MySQL/Adminer")

3-select the "wordpress" database

4-change value:

```
update wp_options set optionvalue='http://localhost' where option_name='siteurl';
```

5-change value:

```
update wp_options set optionvalue='http://localhost' where option_name='home';
```

6-change in "httpd.conf" file (or by de IZ-WAMP Menu "Administration/Configuration Files")

```
[before] Define IZ_WAMP_HTTP_PORT   "8080"

[after]  Define IZ_WAMP_HTTP_PORT   "80"
```

7-restart by the IZ-WAMP Menu "Restart All"

8-go to http://localhost/wordpress to check it works fine again

Comment: be careful, after these changes, some IZ-WAMP menus no longer work. Think about in Z-WAMP\Ressources\iz-wamp-manager\iz-wamp-manager.ini, line: [25] Type: static; Name: WebRoot; Value: "http://localhost:80"

Answer (score 1):

I am the creator of IZ-WAMP from France.
You can go to the IZ-WAMP menu, "Administration / Systems infomations / TCPView". Then go to the "Local Port" column to see which process uses the "http" port.
Also check that your firewall is not blocking the "Apache" application or the "http" port.
Also note that when installing IZ-WAMP, if the port "80" is already used, it will configure you the port "8080". Everything is said during the installation.
Best regards.

Comment: I can't see port 80 used by any app (I sorted the local port to do so), and httpd use "http" which seems weird to me, you can see screen above.

Comment: Good news, the port "http" is the port "80".
Please check that:

1- IZ-WAMP is "Green"?

2- test the page "http://localhost/" which should work?


3- go to the IZ-WAMP menu, "Administration/Check configuration", publish this files without "ipconfig.exe /all" section.


4- go to the IZ-WAMP menu, "Administration/Log files", delete all the files "error_yyyymmdd.log", and restart IZ-WAMP with the menu "Restart All". Please, publish the newly created "error_yyyymmdd.log" file. This file contains Apache startup information (the Http server).

Comment: Finally found why: I had to change Wordpress options table links with 8097 port.